# xrefwrap error: 'void' function returning a value

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, visual-studio-2012, bind

I have got this weird error when compiling my project with Visual Studio 2012:

`error C2562: 'std::_Callable_obj<_Ty>::_ApplyX' : 'void' function returning a value    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xrefwrap`

When jumping in `xrefwrap`, the error comes from this line:

`_VARIADIC_EXPAND_0X(_APPLYX_CALLOBJ, , , , )`

My code compiles fine with GCC on Linux.. Plus the compiler gives me no information on what is causing this error.

What could be the cause of this error? I suspect this piece of code might be the source, but only because I use `std::ref` there:

```
_listener.addSocket(clientSock, std::bind(&Client::handleReceive, &client,
                                          _1, std::ref(*this)),
                    std::bind(&Lounge::handleClientDisconnect, this,
                              std::cref(client)));
```

Here are the two signatures of the member functions I am binding:

```
bool  Client::handleReceive(std::shared_ptr<TBSystem::network::sockets::ITcpSocket>& socket,
                        Lounge& lounge);

void  Lounge::handleClientDisconnect(const Client& c);
```

I do return a value in `Client::handleReceive`.

And this is the two `std::function` prototypes I am using when calling `addSocket`:

```
typedef std::function<bool (std::shared_ptr<sockets::ITcpSocket>&)> readCallback;
typedef std::function<void ()> disconnectCallback;
```

Comment: The error says `'void' function returning a value`. That means you probably need to give us those member functions' signature, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out in one of my file I added a listener with the wrong prototype (`std::plus`)...

```
_listener.addSocket(serverSocket,
                    std::bind(&Lounge::acceptClient, this, _1),
                    std::bind(std::plus<int>(), 0, 0);
```